# Dynamic Routing on Apache Server with subdomains

Tags: linux, apache, routes

So I am setting up a development and public servers and I am trying to figure out how to point apache to a specific folder based on the subdomain.

for example I want subdomain:

projectname.username.dev.domain.com

to point to:

/home/username/projectname/

any idea how to accomplish this without having to set up a separate domain name in my DNS Zone File?

I have all ready set up dev.domain.com and pub.domain.com as subdomains and point them to the appropriate ip addresses.

Comment: For those that were following this I have found the answer I was looking for so I thought I would post it here so that anyone else who had a similar question would find it.

Comment: Adding `*.dev` as a CNAME in my DNS Zone File  allowed for all unassigned `subdomains.dev.domain.com` to be routed to my server. then in my Apache Virtual Host files I used  `VirtualDocumentRoot` and a schema with `path/to/directory` using %1,%2,%3... to point to a directory based on the subdomain.

Comment: What this means is that domain `project.user.dev.domain.com` will now correctly point to my server and the apache VirtualHost file will then route that domain to `/var/www/projects/%2/%1` translated to `/var/www/projects/user/project`